# Can you use multiple app domains in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, appdomain

Can you use multiple app domains in silverlight? If so, are there any special restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean.  By default, each Silverlight application runs in what is, effectively, a separate App Domain.  But you can't programmatically control application domains like you do in the full .NET runtime.  The System.AppDomain namespace is there, but all the "CreateXXXX" methods are missing.  Compare the [.NET 4.0 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain_methods.aspx) with the [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain_methods(VS.95).aspx) docs to see what I mean.

Comment: I have some code that can "leak" into other AppDomains by taking a lock on Type object. I know this is a problem for WPF, but it sounds like it will be for Silverlight as well.